# Como montar um WebService para sincronizar banco de dados SQLite do Android e MySQL

Tags: android, mysql, web-service, sqlite

Montei um app android que armazena no SQLite informações básicas sobre um contato: 
Nome, Telefone, E-mail, Endereço entre outras.

Pesquisei um pouco e pelo que entendi, o que posso fazer é utilizar um WebService, para receber os dados do SQLite, tratá-los e inseri-los no banco de dados utilizando PHP.

Tenho 2 perguntas:

1- Como crio o WebService?

2- O que preciso para realizar a comunicação entre ele e o banco de dados no android? Alguma biblioteca em particular?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode usar a combinação [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org/) + [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/). Explicando um pouco:

- Você deve criar um padrão de dados para que, tanto o seu aplicativo quanto o seu banco de dados remoto possam "entender" as informações que são compartilhadas entre eles. Esse padrão pode ser criado utilizando JSON, pois tanto PHP quanto Android conseguem ler arquivos JSON ( utilizando suas devidas bibliotecas);
- Você deve criar uma API JSON, que será o padrão de comunicação entre o seu aplicativo e o seu banco de dados remoto, ou seja, você deve criar uma "linguagem" de comunicação que o PHP e o Android utilizarão para requisitar e enviar dados entre si;
- No PHP, é muito simples ler e enviar dados em JSON, porém no Android você precisará de uma biblioteca que lê e envia dados JSON de um banco de dados remoto. Essa biblioteca pode ser o Retrofit.

**Um pequeno exemplo:**

- **Padrão de dados**: suponha que os dados dos clientes sejam representados dessa maneira em JSON

  ```
  {
      "cliente": {
          "nome": "joao",
          "email": "emaildojoao",
          "endereco": "enderecodojoao"
      }
  }
  ```
- **API JSON**: agora suponha que você tenha criado uma página **clientes** em seu site e toda que vez que ela fosse acessada ela retornaria um array JSON com todos os clintes do seu banco de dados, portanto, toda vez que o aplicativo quisesse acessar a lista de clientes do banco de dados remoto, ele precisaria acessar o link "/seusite/clientes".
- **Usando Retrofit**: No seu aplicativo,usando Retrofit, você poderia escrever o seguinte código para que sua aplicação pudesse pegar a lista de clientes do site

  ```
  @GET("/users/list")
  List<Cliente> listaDeClientes();
  ```

  Nesse caso, quando você chamasse a função `listaDeClientes()`, ela automaticamente retornaria uma lista de `Cliente`s do seu site.

Lembrando que esta é apenas uma das muitas soluções. Caso você se interesse por esta, dê uma pesquisada mais a fundo e quando você tiver duvidas mais específicas, é só voltar aqui.

Comment: Muito obrigado, é isso mesmo que eu estava procurando. Comecei a utilizar o Gson para converter os objetos em Json, agora vou estudar a Retrofit para fazer a comunicação com o servidor.